# Using Finaliser to do Cleanup - Xunit

Tags: c#, .net, destructor, xunit

I've been using the finaliser to perform cleanup operations in XUnit.

```
    public class CSATWebClientTests
    {
        private readonly        CSATWebServer server;
        private readonly        CSATClient    client;
        private static readonly Random        Rng            = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        private readonly        string        instancePrefix = $"http://localhost:{Rng.Next(20000, 30000)}/";

        public CSATWebClientTests()
        {
            server = new CSATWebServer(new[] {instancePrefix});
            client = new CSATClient(instancePrefix);
            server.Start();
        }

        ~CSATWebClientTests()
        {
            server.Stop();
        }
}
```

This seems to work, but I've had a quick snoop at the docs and it says I should be implementing `IDispose` instead.

Is there any reason why that would be better?

Comment: Be aware that there is a difference between a destructor and a finalizer. In your code you have a finalizer. Please update the question, it will be easier for others to help.

Comment: Using a finalizer is fraught with problems on the *best of days* and usually denotes something wrong. finalizers may never be called, have a thread safety issues, <insert a myriad of other reasons here>. However, all in all, if the docs say use the `IDisposable` *interface*, I would follow the documentation

Comment: @MichaelRandall I intend on it, was more wondering "why" though. Even if it is mostly academic

Comment: Sorry, Microsoft still calls this desctructors even though they have another feature called Desctruct which does some completely different. I stand corrected.

Comment: Finalizers are called when the garbage collector collects the instance. `The programmer has no control over when the finalizer is called; the garbage collector decides when to call it.` Which means it might never be called.

Comment: Even when the application ends, finalizers may never be called. Ergo the problem with them is they are unpredictable. They we added to the language to solve a specific set of problems, and were always problematic, these days there are other ways to solve those problems an as such the use case for them is essentially 0.

Comment: Thank for the comments folks, that clears it up somewhat. I'll leave it an hour in case one of you wants to write up an answer, otherwise I'll put one up myself based on your comments.

Comment: Finalizer will be called by the system, where `Dispose` method will be called by the test runner, what , I think, you would prefer.